# Limit of indicator function

Tags: measure-theory

I am considering the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R},\lambda)$. For every integer $\geq 1$ the function $f_{n}$ is defined as:

$f_{n}=n\cdot \mathbb{1}_{[n,n+n^{-2}]}$

I am asked to show that $f_{n} \to \infty $ for $n \to \infty$ pointwise.

**My attempt**

By the definition of pointwise convergence we would like to analyse the limit of $f_{n}$ when $x$ is fixed and $n \to \infty$.

Now fix $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x_{0} \in [n,n+n^{-2}]$ for an $n_{0}>2$ then $f_{n_{0}}=1$ but then $x_{0} \notin [n,n+n^{-2}]$ for all $N>n_{0}$ since all intervals $[n,n+n^{-2}]$ for $n>2$ are disjoint. This means that all $f_{N>n_{0}}=0$ which shows that $f_{n} \to 0$ when $n \to \infty$.

I have tried to simplify the above by only considering $n>2$. I know that $f_{1}=1$ and $f_{2}=2$ at the same time only when $n=2$.

Feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: $f_{n}\rightarrow 0$ is the right one.

Comment: Is my argument fine?

Comment: The argument is sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can choose at the very beginning for each fixed $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ some $n_{0}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{0}>x$, then apparently $f_{n}(x_{0})=0$ for all such $n\geq n_{0}$.